# ¿Como simplificar la modificacion de los atributos de cada objeto? JAVA

Tags: java, objeto

Estoy recién introduciéndome en **Java** y estoy tratando de resolver algunos ejercicios. ¿Hay una forma correcta de simplificar esto mismo?

Para no estar pidiendo tantos ingresos y mostrando tantos mensajes. Se me ocurre con un `for` pero no se cual es la forma, ya que no se como hacer para que luego de ingresar los 4 atributos del primer objeto, salte directamente a pisar los del otro objeto.

**Código**:

```
    Superhéroe superheroe1 = new Superhéroe(nombre1, fuerza1, resistencia1, superpoderes1);
    Superhéroe superheroe2 = new Superhéroe(nombre2, fuerza2, resistencia2, superpoderes2);

    mensaje(msj_nom);
    nombre1 = input.nextLine();
    superheroe1.setNombre(nombre1);

    mensaje(msj_fuerza);
    fuerza1 = input.nextInt();
    superheroe1.setFuerza(fuerza1);

    mensaje(msj_resist);
    resistencia1 = input.nextInt();
    superheroe1.setResistencia(resistencia1);

    mensaje(msj_superpod);
    superpoderes1 = input.nextInt();
    superheroe1.setSuperpoderes(superpoderes1);
    input.nextLine();

    mensaje(msj_nom);
    nombre2 = input.nextLine();
    superheroe2.setNombre(nombre2);

    mensaje(msj_fuerza);
    fuerza2 = input.nextInt();
    superheroe2.setFuerza(fuerza2);

    mensaje(msj_resist);
    resistencia2 = input.nextInt();
    superheroe2.setResistencia(resistencia2);

    mensaje(msj_superpod);
    superpoderes2 = input.nextInt();
    superheroe2.setSuperpoderes(superpoderes2);

    System.out.println(superheroe1.getNombre() + " vs. " + superheroe2.getNombre());
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Puedes hacer el bucle teniendo una lista o array de superheroes

Answer (score 1):

Metes todos los objetos superheroe en un arraylist y luego lo recorres en un for seteando todas las caracteristicas. No crees nuevas variables para las caracteristicas de cada superheroes. Añadele a la clase `superheroe` los setters y getters

Primero añadimos los setters y getters

```
public class Superheroe
{
  private String nombre;
  private int fuerza;
  private int resistencia;
  private int superpoderes;

  public Superheroe()
  {
  //Constructor por defecto
  }

  public void setNombre(final String nombre)
  {
    this.nombre=nombre;
  }
  public String getNombre()
  {
    return nombre;
  }
  // Repetir getters y setters para las otras variables

}
```

Y ahora modificamos tu codigo al siguiente código

```
ArrayList<Superheroe> superheroes = new ArrayList();

Superhéroe superheroe1 = new Superhéroe();
Superhéroe superheroe2 = new Superhéroe();

superheroes.add(superheroe1);
superheroes.add(superheroe2);

for(Superheroe i:superheroes)
{
  i.setNombre(input.nextLine());
  i.setFuerza(input.nextInt());
  i.setResitencia(input.nextInt());
  i.setSuperpoderes(input.nextInt());
  input.nextLine();
}
System.out.println(superheroe1.getNombre() + " vs. " + superheroe2.getNombre());
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías pedir todos los datos a la vez, obtenerles todos juntos y separarles, o, pedirle al usuario de primeras que introduzca los datos del superhéroe y lo creas con el constructor. En tu código, realmente ya tienes tus superhéroes creados, sólo les modificas sus atributos. Si haces una función en la que el usuario intruduzca los parámetros...

Edit:

(hacer un input separado por comas) "nombre",20,20,10

```
vars[]=input.nextLine().split(",")// Se debe declarar antes
superHeroe=new SuperHeroe(vars[0],vars[1],vars[2],vars[3]);
```